# more efficient way to check 2 array foreach values

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a more efficient way to foreach check an array for similar values against multiple arrays?
Here's my code:

```
foreach ($city as $option) {
    if (in_array($option, $optionarray1)) {
        $tables[] = 'newvalue1';
    } else if (in_array($option, $optionarray2)) {
        $tables[] = 'newvalue2';
    } else if (in_array($option, $optionarray3)) {
        $tables[] = 'newvalue3';
    }
 }
```

Comment: given you're adding different values for each comparison, no... not really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_flip()` to turn each `$optionarrayX` into an associative array, so you don't have to do linear searches each time.

```
$optionhash1 = array_flip($optionarray1);
$optionhash2 = array_flip($optionarray2);
$optionhash3 = array_flip($optionarray3);
```

Then you can put these all in an array, so you can use a nested loop instead of repeating code.

```
$optionhashes = array(1=>$optionhash1, 2=>$optionhash2, 3=>$optionhash3);

foreach ($city as $option) {
    foreach ($optionhashes as $i => $hash) {
        if (array_key_exists($option, $hash)) {
            $tables[]= 'newvalue' . $i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```